# FFMPEG-NORMALIZE does not recognize special characters in audio names files

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, metadata

When I run ffmpeg-normalize it displays the name of the input audio with codes in place of the special character, see below:

Command:

```
ffmpeg-normalize "Barão Vermelho - Agora Tudo Acabou.mp3" -nt ebu -t -10 -tp -0.5 -c:a mp3 -b:a 320k -ar 44100 --extra-output-options "-c:v copy -id3v2_version 3 -metadata:s:v title=""Album cover"" -metadata:s:v comment=""Cover (front)""" -o "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\Converting_lufs\Barão Vermelho - Agora Tudo Acabou_normalized.mp3" -p
```

Command output:

```
[
    {
        "input_file": "Bar\u00e3o Vermelho - Agora Tudo Acabou.mp3",
        "output_file": "C:\\Users\\CMG\\Desktop\\Converting_lufs\\Bar\u00e3o Vermelho - Agora Tudo Acabou_normalized.mp3",
        "stream_id": 0,
        "ebu": {
            "input_i": -7.22,
            "input_tp": 1.49,
            "input_lra": 3.5,
            "input_thresh": -17.35,
            "output_i": -9.34,
            "output_tp": -0.5,
            "output_lra": 2.3,
            "output_thresh": -19.42,
            "normalization_type": "dynamic",
            "target_offset": -0.66
        },
        "mean": null,
        "max": null
    }
]
```

Note in the command that the input audio file name is:
`Barão Vermelho - Agora Tudo Acabou.mp3`

And in the command output display it shows:
`Bar\u00e3o Vermelho - Agora Tudo Acabou.mp3` for both input and output file.

The special character `ã`, is exchanged for `\u00e3`

When I run normalization without using ffmpeg-normalize, it doesn't, see below:

Command:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -i "Barão Vermelho - Agora Tudo Acabou.mp3" -af "loudnorm=linear=true:I=-10:LRA=11:tp=-0.5:measured_I=I:measured_LRA=LRA:measured_tp=TP:measured_thresh=TT:offset=TO:print_format=summary" -c:v copy -id3v2_version 3 -metadata:s:v title="Album cover" -metadata:s:v comment="Cover (front)" -acodec mp3 -b:a 320k -ar:a 44100 "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\Converting_lufs\Barão Vermelho - Agora Tudo Acabou_normalized.mp3"
```

Command output:

```
Input #0, mp3, from 'Barão Vermelho - Agora Tudo Acabou.mp3':
  Metadata:
    title           : Agora Tudo Acabou
    artist          : Barão Vermelho
    comment         :
    album           : CMG Clássicos Pop Rock Nacionais
    genre           : Clássico Pop Rock Nacional
    date            : 1987
    encoder         : Lavf59.6.100
  Duration: 00:03:33.31, start: 0.023021, bitrate: 320 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 320 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc59.12
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mp3 (mp3float) -> mp3 (libmp3lame))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help

Output #0, mp3, to 'C:\Users\CMG\Desktop\Converting_lufs\Barão Vermelho - Agora Tudo Acabou_normalized.mp3':
  Metadata:
    TIT2            : Agora Tudo Acabou
    TPE1            : Barão Vermelho
    comment         :
    TALB            : CMG Clássicos Pop Rock Nacionais
    TCON            : Clássico Pop Rock Nacional
    TYER            : 1987
    TSSE            : Lavf59.17.102
  Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 320 kb/s
```

And in the command output display it shows:
`Barão Vermelho - Agora Tudo Acabou.mp3` correctly for both input and output file.

Also note that the path to the output file in ffmpeg-normalize contains `\\` two slashes, and the path to the output file without using ffmpeg-normalize contains only `\` one slashe.

Does ffmpeg-normalize not recognize special characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FFmpeg-normalize does recognise special characters, but the way the data is being outputted does not support such special characters.

FFmpeg-normalize is displaying the output of the loudnorm filter's first pass as JSON. What you're seeing in place of the special character and single backslash are JSON escape sequences.

---

> The special character ã, is exchanged for \u00e3

Since `ã` is not an ascii character, it must be escaped as valid JSON cannot contain non-ascii characters. A backslash (`\`) character is used to signify the start of the escape sequence, and the `u` signifies a unicode escape sequence. This is followed by the UTF-16 encoding of the character, `00E3` which gets you the `\u00E3` seen in the output.

> Also note that the path to the output file in ffmpeg-normalize contains \ two slashes, and the path to the output file without using ffmpeg-normalize contains only \ one slashe.

Since the backslash character is used to start an escape sequence, it cannot be used normally and has to be escaped itself if you wish to have a backslash in a string. A backslash is escaped with a double backslash (`\\`)

Comment: Is there any way to change the print-format of ffmpeg-normalize to a format that accepts the special characters of my language?

Comment: @Clamarc There doesn't appear to be an option in ffmpeg-normalize for that. However it shouldn't be too much of an issue, since if you're going to be parsing the JSON it will still show the original file names without the escapes

Comment: ok thanks for the help.